# Low-level details of the implementation of performSelectorOnMainThread:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Was wondering if anyone knows, or has pointers to good documentation that discusses, the low-level implementation details of Cocoa's 'performSelectorOnMainThread:' method.

My best guess, and one I think is probably pretty close, is that it uses mach ports or an abstraction on top of them to provide intra-thread communication, passing selector information along as part of the mach message.

Right? Wrong?

**Update 09:39AMPST**

Thank you Evan DiBiase and Mecki for the answers, but to clarify: I understand what happens in the run loop, but what I'm looking for an answer to is; "*where* is the method getting queued? *how* is the selector information getting passed into the queue?" Looking for more than Apple's doc info: I've read 'em

**Update 14:21PST**

Chris Hanson brings up a good point in a comment: my objective here is not to learn the underlying mechanisms in order to take advantage of them in my own code. Rather, I'm just interested in a better conceptual understanding of the process of signaling another thread to execute code. As I said, my own research leads me to believe that it takes advantage of mach messaging for IPC to pass selector information between threads, but I'm specifically looking for **concrete** information on what is happening, so I can be sure I'm understanding things *correctly*. Thanks!

**Update 03/06/09**

I'm look for the **lowest-level detail** of the mechanism used by `performSelectorOnMainThread:` and the like, and as I mentioned earlier, I suspect it has something to do with Mach ports but I'd really like to know for sure.

Comment: It might be useful if you explained why you thought you needed to know the exact mechanism used.  If you want or feel you need to rely on it in your application-level code, there's a good chance you're incorrect...

Comment: Good point! Addressed in an edit that hopefully sheds more light onto what I'm after.

Comment: I doubt you're likely to get concrete information, as the code in question is not Open Source.

Comment: Another excellent point, but I was hoping someone might know or have done similar research anyway. Oh well, it was worth a shot! :)

Comment: I'd like to know this too. I've noticed that after calling performSelectorOnMainThread from the main thread my app is considered "multithreaded" by NSThread. Strange, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it does use Mach ports. What happens is this:

1. A block of data encapsulating the perform info (the target object, the selector, the optional object argument to the selector, etc.) is enqueued in the thread's run loop info. This is done using `@synchronized`, which ultimately uses `pthread_mutex_lock`.
2. CFRunLoopSourceSignal is called to signal that the source is ready to fire.
3. CFRunLoopWakeUp is called to let the main thread's run loop know it's time to wake up. This is done using mach_msg.

From the Apple docs:

> Version 1 sources are managed by the run loop and kernel. These sources use Mach ports to signal when the sources are ready to fire. A source is automatically signaled by the kernel when a message arrives on the source’s Mach port. The contents of the message are given to the source to process when the source is fired. The run loop sources for CFMachPort and CFMessagePort are currently implemented as version 1 sources.

I'm looking at a stack trace right now, and this is what it shows:

```
0 mach_msg
1 CFRunLoopWakeUp
2 -[NSThread _nq:]
3 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:]
4 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]
```

Set a breakpoint on mach_msg and you'll be able to confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for NSObject's `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` method](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:) says:

> This method queues the message on the run loop of the main thread using the default run loop modes—that is, the modes associated with the [NSRunLoopCommonModes](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSRunLoopCommonModes) constant. As part of its normal run loop processing, the main thread dequeues the message (assuming it is running in one of the default run loop modes) and invokes the desired method.

Answer (score 2):

One More Edit:

To answer the question of the comment:

> what IPC mechanism is being used to
>   pass info between threads? Shared
>   memory? Sockets? Mach messaging?

NSThread stores internally a reference to the main thread and via that reference you can get a reference to the NSRunloop of that thread. A NSRunloop internally is a linked list and by adding a NSTimer object to the runloop, a new linked list element is created and added to the list. So you could say it's shared memory, the linked list, that actually belongs to the main thread, is simply modified from within a different thread. There are mutexes/locks (possibly even NSLock objects) that will make sure editing the linked list is thread-safe.

Pseudo code:

```
// Main Thread

for (;;) {
    lock(runloop->runloopLock);
    task = NULL;
    do {
        task = getNextTask(runloop);
        if (!task) {
            // function below unlocks the lock and
            // atomically sends thread to sleep.
            // If thread is woken up again, it will
            // get the lock again before continuing
            // running. See "man pthread_cond_wait"
            // as an example function that works
            // this way
            wait_for_notification(runloop->newTasks, runloop->runloopLock);
        }
    } while (!task);
    unlock(runloop->runloopLock);
    processTask(task);
}


// Other thread, perform selector on main thread
// selector is char *, containing the selector
// object is void *, reference to object

timer = createTimerInPast(selector, object);
runloop = getRunloopOfMainThread();
lock(runloop->runloopLock);
addTask(runloop, timer);
wake_all_sleeping(runloop->newTasks);
unlock(runloop->runloopLock);
```

Of course this is oversimplified, most details are hidden between functions here. E.g. getNextTask will only return a timer, if the timer should have fired already. If the fire date for every timer is still in the future and there is no other event to process (like a keyboard, mouse event from UI or a sent notification), it would return NULL.

---

I'm still not sure what the question is. A **selector** is nothing more than a C string containing the name of a method being called. Every method is a normal C function and there exists a string table, containing the method names as strings and function pointers. That are the very basics how Objective-C actually works.

As I wrote below, a NSTimer object is created that gets a pointer to the target object and a pointer to a C string containing the method name and when the timer fires, it finds the right C method to call by using the string table (hence it needs the string name of the method) of the target object (hence it needs a reference to it).

Not exactly the implementation, but pretty close to it:

Every thread in Cocoa has a NSRunLoop (it's always there, you never need to create on for a thread). PerformSelectorOnMainThread creates a NSTimer object like [this](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:), one that fires only once and where the time to fire is already located in the past (so it needs firing immediately), then gets the NSRunLoop of the main thread and adds the timer object there. As soon as the main thread goes *idle*, it searches for the next event in its Runloop to process (or goes to sleep if there is nothing to process and being woken up again as soon as an event is added) and performs it. Either the main thread is busy when you schedule the call, in which case it will process the timer event as soon as it has finished its current task or it is sleeping at the moment, in which case it will be woken up by adding the event and processes it immediately.

A good source to look up how Apple is *most likely doing it* (nobody can say for sure, as after all its closed source) is GNUStep. Since the GCC can handle Objective-C (it's not just an extension only Apple ships, even the standard GCC can handle it), however, having Obj-C without all the basic classes Apple ships is rather useless, the GNU community tried to re-implement the most common Obj-C classes you use on Mac and their implementation is OpenSource.

[Here](ftp://ftp.gnustep.org/pub/daily-snapshots/core.20080925.tar.bz2) you can download a recent source package.

Unpack that and have a look at the implementation of NSThread, NSObject and NSTimer for details. I guess Apple is not doing it much different, I could probably prove it using gdb, but why would they do it much different than that approach? It's a clever approach that works very well :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the concerted effort Mecki, and I'm commenting just to let you know why I'm not marking your post as a proper answer: timers and selectors are not the question, but rather; what IPC mechanism is being used to pass info between threads? Shared memory? Sockets? Mach messaging?

Comment: And, while GNUStep is a great resource in general, it doesn't help here because it is essentially written on top of what looks like a POSIX API, which in OS X is implemented on top of lower-level subsystems like Mach. As Chris Hanson says, the answer is elusive because it's most likely closed-source

Comment: Actually Mac OS is one of the little, true POSIX conform systems and speculating that Apple does not use a POSIX call if there is one and instead uses some obscure Mach call is just that, pure speculation. Actually using DTrace on Leopard shows that Obj-C uses lots of POSIX calls.

Answer (score 0):

As Mecki said, a more general mechanism that could be used to implement `-performSelectorOn…` is `NSTimer`.

`NSTimer` is toll-free bridged to `CFRunLoopTimer`. An implementation of `CFRunLoopTimer` – although not necessarily the one actually used for normal processes in OS X – can be found in CFLite (open-source subset of CoreFoundation; package CF-476.14 in the [Darwin 9.4 source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/darwinsource/10.5.4/). (CF-476.15, corresponding to OS X 10.5.5, is not yet available.)