# Calling performSelectorOnMainThread => Multithreaded app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multithreading

I noticed that the following banal call from my main thread

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(rollBar:)
      withObject:nil
      waitUntilDone:false];
```

was causing `[NSThread isMultiThreaded]` to report that my app
had become multithreaded. I thought that was only supposed
to happen when you detach a thread, something that queueing
a message within one thread shouldn't need to do.

Any insights?

This question not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149388/low-level-details-of-the-implementation-of-performselectoronmainthread) one.

**Stop the press**
My fault, `rollBar:` called `[m_progress_bar incrementBy: 0.5];`.
The the pretty, lickable, animating `NSProgressIndicator` is responsible
for making my app become multithreaded. Which is surprising.
I didn't know that.

Surprisingly, `[m_progress_bar usesThreadedAnimation]` always
returns `NO`, even though the bar animates when my app is hung.

Comment: But if you're trying to run something (within the main thread) and not willing to wait until this operation is done ("waitUntilDone: false") doesn't that automatically mean you must have at least two threads?

Comment: No, you're just posting events to your own thread's queue.
At least that's what you'd expect. Hang about though, I've
figured it out: I did something dumb, but the result was surprising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure about this? I put the following code in my appDelegate's init method:

`NSLog(@"Multi-threaded before? %@", [NSThread isMultiThreaded] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
[self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(setDelegate:) withObject: self waitUntilDone: NO];
NSLog(@"Multi-threaded after? %@", [NSThread isMultiThreaded] ? @"Yes" : @"No");`

and got this result in the console:

`2008-10-21 07:26:28.296 MyApplication[82963:20b] Multi-threaded before? No
2008-10-21 07:26:28.297 MyApplication[82963:20b] Multi-threaded after? No`

I also added the second `NSLog(...)` statement to my applicationWillTerminate: method and it also told me it was not multithreaded.

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track. The NSProgressIndicator in
rollBar: made my app become multithreaded. Who knew!?